# Multiple if() in one

Tags: php, javascript, c++

This:

```
if (A || B) { X; }
if (C && D) { X; }
if (F != G && H + I === J) { X; }
```

Can be replaced by:

```
if ((A || B) || (C && D) || (F != G && H + I === J)) { X; }
```

But can it be replaced by:

```
if (A || B || C && D || F != G && H + I === J) { X; }
```

? (Without parentheses)

And is there any difference between languages?

P.S: The answers shouldn't based on those examples.

Comment: FYI, the first code example isn't equivalent to the second. The second can only run `X` once, but the first can run it thrice.

Comment: @Blender Thanks. It's equivalent if `X` is `foo=3;` for example.

Comment: @djechlin has given the answer. But finally it decreases the readability. As you said if x is foo=3, in terms of readability the best is your second statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One, this is all invalid if these have side-effects.

Two, only if X is idempotent, which is a fancy way of saying, if X can be called twice with no change on the second time.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

`&&` binds tigther than `||`, so yes, you may drop parens around `&&` in this context.  The operator precedence rules I believe hold valid for any language that has them, I don't know any counterexamples to this, and the languages you asked about do follow C operator precedence rules.

Comment: Then, `if(A){X;}if(B){X;}` can always be replaced by `if(A||B){X;}`? No matter what A and B are?

Comment: No.  If A is `returnTrue() and B is `blowUptheWorldThenReturnTrue()` you may have an unintended result in the former case.  If X is `i++` then no because in the former case `i` is added twice.  Look up short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Almost everything has precedence over || so yes it should still work.

This should also hold for Java, and also why?

Comment: @Mageek If anyone saw this in commercial code they would poo their pants. But i guess it is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your first equivalence statement is not correct at least in C++. This

```
if(A||B){X;}
if(C&&D){X;}
if(F!=G&&H+I==J){X;}
```

can execute `X` more than once if more than one condition is true. Also, the above is guaranteed to evaluate at least `A`, `C`, `F` and `G`. Meanwhile this

```
if((A||B) || (C&&D) || (F!=G&&H+I===J)){X;}
```

is guaranteed to execute `X` only once and it is only guaranteed to evaluate at least `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it doesn't show much difference because && has higher priority that ||